# Why browsers keeps old code in symfony 4?

Tags: html, css, symfony, caching

I have app in symfony 4, but sometimes when I have changed something this is not refreshed on page in browser.

**Example.**

I have class `col-md-5` and is change to `col-md-3` and then is refreshing page and there is still `col-md-5`. It's strange.

Similar is with CSS. I have `width: 50%;`, then I change  to 10%, then refresh page and still is width 50%.

I have to change something else in code, write something, some text and then refresh and is ok, is refreshed. Or after clear cache in symfony is ok.

It's standard symfony 4 app.

It's dev mode and twig cache is disabled. Guys, where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to clear opcache?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Chrome cache is a bit "strong". Open console (f12), press F1, and check "Disable HTTP cache when console is open". It should void cache as long as console is open.

Comment: I know what is, PHPStorm autosave sometimes dont work, sometimes when I change only class in html or only one line in .css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the cache. if the browser does not detect a big change, it will keep "previous version". You should save in PHPStorm (or your text editor, probably Ctrl+S), and if the changes do not appear, you can refresh your browser without cache: CTRL+R.

If your app is in production or change still not appear you can clear the cache. In symfony you can use the command :

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

or alias :

```
bin/console c:c
```

I hope it will help, feel free to ask if you want more info.